# CSS wrap list around image without background appearing behind

Tags: html, css

I have looked at all the similar questions which suggest:

1. Adding overflow: auto to the `<ul />`.
2. Float the `<li />` left.

Both cause the list to either display below the image or in a column to the left of the image. I want the list to wrap around the image. Is this possible?

In the example I have used a border instead of background
http://jsfiddle.net/jvh6N/

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jvh6N/9/) what you want ?

Comment: No, I want the li's to wrap round the image include the borders/background. In your example the border is going behind the image

Comment: UL is block level, so as a container, it's the UL that has to interact with the image.  jsFiddle's in maintenance - check back later.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with floating the `<li>`? You just need to have it be the first `<li>` for the other ones to wrap around it:

```
  li:first-child { float: left; }
```

http://jsbin.com/ekonuf/